# How do I use filter search table in my Django project

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms, django-filters

How do I go about assertationError when using django-filter in my Django project
assertationError:setting 'Meta.model' without either 'Meta.fields' or 'Meta.exclude' has been deprecated.

Comment: Share you filterset.